# How to use PHP to Create JSON File without column names?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a MySQL View that returns 2 fields.

```
partId CHAR(20)
partCount INT
```

I want to create a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{"1152471600":1,"1153681200":1,"1155409200":1}
```

I've tried numerous approaches and this is the closest that I've got.

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);     
$resultArray = array();   
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $resultArray[] = array($row["partId"], $row["partCount"]);
   };
};
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

This returns:

```
[[1152471600,1],[1153681200,1],[1155409200,1]]
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the partId as a key in an associative array:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $resultArray[$row["partId"]] = $row["partCount"];
```

Note, this will only work correctly if partId is unique.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much.